# Javascript Redirection Goes Wrong on Tumblr Blog

Tags: javascript, http-status-code-404, tumblr, redirect

So Tumblr is showing many 404 pages, which I want to redirect to the homepage. Unfortunately, due to my mad coding skills (read: no coding skills), I am still unable to make this code work.

Here it is:

```
`<script type="text/javascript"
      src="http://static.tumblr.com/5huhcpw/k3elvd7u3/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript"> $( init ); 
      function init() {
     var pageTitle = $('h2').text();
     if (pageTitle == "Not Found”):
     redirect( 'http://example.com/', 301 ); 
      exit;
      endif;
      }
     </script>`
```

Every Tumblr 404 page has a "Not Found" title. Now, if we see this text it should 301 to the homepage. Is this possible? Appreciate your help. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have php and javascript/jquery mixed up possibly.

I managed to get the following code to work:

```
 var pageTitle = $('h2').text();
 if (pageTitle == "Not Found") {
     window.location.replace('http://example.com/'); 
 }
```

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YQsDv/

Comment: Oops! one problem: redirection tools says the page is 404. We are not 301'ing right? Any other way around this? I want the bots to know we are 301'ing to the homepage. :-)

Comment: You can't do a 301 redirect for 404s on Tumblr. Google sees javascript redirects too but it won't matter because the page was already correctly served as 404 Not Found.